# Browser does not play YouTube video

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, video, flash, youtube

Whenever I click on any direct link to a video it opens a completely blank page, though I can download any video by using download manager software and also see video from the user page [ex: `http://www.youtube.com/user/xxx`].

I have updated my browsers [Chrome and Firefox] and also Flash Player. I am running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit with Norton 2013.

How can I get to see video via clicking on a direct link?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a issue with your flash-player but rather your internet firewall - try loading a video After disabling Norton.

Comment: @dashboard Yes it helps but how to solve the problem permanently ?

Comment: @Sourav try to add the www.youtube.com as a trusted site in firewall setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think Norton has a "temporary disable" button somewhere. Not too sure though, but I would just try disabling norton for a small bit and see if you can play youtube videos. If, after disabling youtube, you are able to play youtube videos you might have to play around with Norton on adding it to exceptions or something.

Sorry if this didn't help! Good luck!

Comment: Yes it helps but how to solve the problem permanently ? I tried but can't find such settings. I've Norton AV 2013

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the smart firewall.
1.In the Norton Internet Security main window, click Settings.
2.In the Settings window, click the Network tab.
3.In the left pane, click Smart Firewall.
4.In the Smart Firewall row, move the On/Off switch to the right to the Off position.
5.Click Apply.
6.In the Security Request window, in the Select the duration drop-down list, select the duration for which you want to turn off Smart Firewall.
6.Click OK.
7.Click OK.